# Send a post request in JSON format

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

Below is the format of post request expected in JSON. Can anyone please tell me how to achieve this.

```
{
  "MywebServiceInputDetail":{
     "MyDatalst":{
       "MyData":[
          {
           "name":"TestName",
           "id":"2611201",
           "SomeRefVal":"REF123456"
           }
          ]
        }
      }
}
```

I am using JavaScriptSerializer as of now.
Below is the code.

```
[Serializable]
public struct MyStruct
{
     public string name;
     public string id;
     public string refno;
}


JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
string serializedJson = jss.Serialize(ObjMystrcut);
```

Above code results in the JSON string as

```
{"name":"TestName","id":"1234567","refno":"567123"}
```

I am new to JSON so I'm not able to formulate the request format.
I am avoiding to achieve it by hardcoding a json string. Basically, I am trying to understand what does `{` and `[` bracketing mean.

Does `[` mean that I need to create an array of objects?

Comment: You only defined your innermost type. You also need to define the wrappers which contain the `List<MyStruct> MyData` and `MyDataList` and `MywebSercieInputDetail` properties. And then you must serialize the outermost object

Comment: `[ ]` tells you that you are working with a collection of objects, in this case MyData Objects. If a parent only contains one child then we use `{ }`

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
string serializedJson = jss.Serialize(new { MywebServiceInputDetail = new { MyDatalst = new { MyData = new[] { ObjMystrcut } } } });
```

{} is object notation, so it represents an object, with properties.
[] is an array notation.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the `[` and `]` symbols represent JSON arrays (collections of objects). In your example, `MyData` is a collection of those structs you created.

You need to create the following classes:

```
public class MywebServiceInputDetail
{
    public MyDatalst MyDatalst { get; set; }
}

public class MyDatalst
{
    public List<MyStruct> MyData { get; set; }
}

public struct MyStruct
{
    public string name;
    public string id;
    public string SomeRefVal;
}
```

Now create a MywebServiceInputDetail object and serialize it.

Personally I would forget about using a struct and just create the following class instead:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string SomeRefVal { get; set; }
}
```

You should also add JSON attributes to the properties to make sure Name and Id are serialized with lowercase letters.